# Почему сейчас популярны горизонтальные меню?

Tags: html, веб-дизайн

На сколько я помню, раньше почти на каждом сайте была боковая вертикальная менюшка, а сейчас же 90% сайтов имею горизонтальное меню, которое при уменьшении размеров трансформируется в вертикальные. Очевидно, у этого должно быть логическое обоснование.

Comment: удобно когда меню сверху, а твой контент использует всю ширину страницы.

Comment: @user190134 нихрена не удобно. Неспроста ВК, Хабр и Stack Overflow ограничивают ширину контента

Comment: Спрашивайте у дизайнеров, это их стихия, а не наша)

Comment: Это все очень субъективно. Кому-то нравится вертикальные, кому-то меню сверху. Если слишком много элементов меню, то меню слева лучше будет, я так думаю. Лично мне больше нравится меню слева,

Comment: Наверное у кого-то популярного получилось в самом деле красиво с верхней менюшкой и 90% стада начали обезъянничать

Answer (score 3):

Горизонтальное и вертикальное меню сейчас зачастую создают 2 вида группировки:

1 - наиболее востребованные пункты меню, связанные с основной темой сайта, обычно располагаются в горизонтальном меню. Горизонтальное меню практически всегда остается на виду, для малых экранов его часто сворачивают в одну кнопку, по клику на которую появляются все его пункты.

2 - вертикальное меню чаще содержит ссылки на второстепенные / дополнительные страницы, представляющие меньший интерес для большей части посетителей. Вертикальное меню при уменьшении экрана часто помещают вниз - над футером, чтобы оно не отвлекало от основного контента.